# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS plicy

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am building e-commerce in angular and nodejs and I am getting this error when I am trying to get the products:
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/products?limit=10' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
**
I have already installed cors and used it in my app.js file in the backend.
Here is my code:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  products: any[] = [];


  constructor(private productService: ProductService,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe((prods: { count: Number, products: any[] }) => {
      this.products = prods.products;
    });
  }

  selectProduct(id: Number) {
    this.router.navigate(['/product', id]).then();
  }
}
```

this was my home.component.ts

```
export class ProductService {

  private SERVER_URL = environment.SERVER_URL;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  /* This is to fetch all products from the backend server */
  getAllProducts(numberOfResults= 10) {
    return this.http.get(this.SERVER_URL + '/products', {
      params: {
        limit: numberOfResults.toString()
      }
    });
  }

}
```

and this was my product.service.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to allow Cross-origin in your application, meaning what websites can communicate with your back-end application, in this the other website will be the front-end which is at localhost:4200 you can allow this by typing this in your Nodejs app

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,OPTIONS");
  if (req.method == "OPTIONS") {
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  next();
});
```

the code above sets the headers as you see to allow CORS.